# Sending an email from a distribution list

Tags: hmail-server

I am using hMail server, and I have a distribution list within one of my accounts.  I would like to know if it's possible to send an email from the distribution list, or is it not really an "account"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My initial response would be that, being a "distribution list" - you will only be able to retrieve mail. Not send it.

Comment: This was my initial thoughts.  Just after a bit of clarity.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to send a mail from a distribution list id. Check the following link

[Issue with sending mails from a distribution mail id [Python]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9972216/issue-with-sending-mails-from-a-distribution-mail-id-python/9972605#9972605)